# Uninstalling PowerShell 1.0 before installing Sharepoint 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, installation, windows-server-2008

While going through the book "Beginning Sharepoint 2010 Administration", the author was discussing on how to prepare for SharePoint 2010 server installation on win2008 R2 server. In that one of the step being uninstalling powershell 1.0, I don't understand the reason behind this.

Please help me to understand why one should uninstall this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upgrading to PowerShell V2 would make more sense.

Comment: @Richard: So instead of uninstalling I could upgrade to PS 2 and continue with Sharepoint 2010 server installation. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If the book is [this one](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-sharepoint/9780470597125) then I think you are referring to the instructions (in §A.1.5) for Server 2008 and not Server 2008 **R2**. Better to go to Technet to double check things: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608031.aspx *And* consider that Server 2008 R2 comes with PowerShell V2 and not V1. (I'd missed the precise server version).

Comment: @Richard: Yeah its the same book which I was referring to. The Technet link was really helpful thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell V1.0 was present on Windows Server 2008.

On Windows server 2008 R2 PowerShell 2.0 is natively present, so no need to upgrade it. You can refer to these StackOverflow articles:

[Why is Powershell 2.0 installed in the same location as Powershell 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415259/why-is-powershell-2-0-installed-in-the-same-location-as-powershell-1-0/5415846#5415846)

[Determine What Version of PowerShell is Installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed)